# Ruby On Rails = Compare ActiveRecord to Array with thousands or records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an incoming CSV with about 500,000 records (csv_data).
Want to compare it to previous data stored within the ActiveRecord (PreviousData).

Currently have this so far but fails since it's taking a long time to compare large data sets. How would I optimize this to handle larger data sets?

```
added = csv_data.select{|item| !PreviousData.where(iden: item[:iden]).exists?}
```

Comment: why do you need to compare it with previous data, what you will do next(after the comparison) with the incoming data? those details would help in arriving at a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable#each_slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) to do it in chunks:

```
exists = csv_data.each_slice(1000).map do |chunk|
  PreviousData.where(id: chunk.map { |item| item[:iden] })
              .pluck(:id)
end.flatten
```

This will do one SQL query per 1000 rows in the CSV file instead of one per row which will make a huge performance difference. You can of course play around with the batch size to tweak memory consumption VS the number of DB queries.

You can also use `with_index` if you want to keep track of which slice you are currently on:

```
exists = csv_data.each_slice(1000).with_index.map do |chunk, index|
  puts "Importing chunk #{index}"
  PreviousData.where(id: chunk.map { |item| item[:iden] })
              .pluck(:id)
end.flatten
```

If what you're doing is creating records from the CSV file you will want to look into using UPSERT if available and wrapping the creation in a single transaction or doing a batch INSERT/UPSERT.

Comment: Thank you! this was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

In simple way you can try like this:

```
stored_idens = PreviousData.pluck(:iden)
new_records = csv_data.reject { |item| stored_idens.include?(item[:iden]) }
```

Happy Coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should prepare a list of values to check, and then with one single query check all of them.

I'm assuming that `:iden` column has a uniq value:

```rb
# Stores all the `:iden` values from your `csv_data` variable
idens = csv_data.map{ |item| item[:iden] }

# A single query checking that all of them are present in the PreviousData's table
PreviousData.where(iden: idens).exists?
```

This should produce only one query (not tested)